# Pass Through Query Won't Run From Command Line

Tags: vba, ms-access

I created a pass through query in Access.

All it says is .
    sp_Submit ''

If I click on it directly it runs the SSMS stored procedure which just changes some test tables.

However if I run it in VBA it does not work.  It doesn't error out or anything, it just does not work.

I have tried

```
sSQL = "sp_Submit '" & Me.cboNumber & "'"
```

and

```
 sSQL = "sp_Submit '"
```

Please not the stored procedure isn't doing anything much at this point.  I have it testing some stuff. It just deletes everything in one table and inserts it in another.

What am I doing wrong?  I've used this in the past and it has worked so I'm not sure why it doesn't work this time.   The stored procedure itself is set up to accept one variable but it doesn't actually do anything with it (yet.).

Thank you.

Comment: You have shown the code where you put something into a `String` variable, but perhaps also showing the code where you execute that command in VBA might be useful.

Comment: That's all I have in VB.  Is that what I'm missing?

Comment: Apparently so.  That was it, thank you.

Comment: For the record, this is what I added...DoCmd.OpenQuery "sp_Submit"

Comment: Put that as a self-answer if you think other people might have similar issues in the future.  (But, if you do, it would be useful to edit the question to mention that your code consists **only** of the statement shown and, I assume, a `Sub` and `End Sub`.)

Comment: And, FWIW, what you should have added was `DoCmd.OpenQuery sSQL` - there is no point creating a variable to hold the text of the query you want to execute if you don't then use that variable when doing the query.  If you just use `DoCmd.OpenQuery "sp_Submit"` then there is no point creating the `sSQL` variable.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense.  I never understood that but just did it because that's how all of our other programs are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given what you have to far, then you should be able to edit the saved pass though query with

```
Sp_Submit 'test'
```

Assuming the 1 paramter is text. If the parameter is to be a number, then

```
Sp_Submit 123
```

At this point, you have to save that query. Now click on it, does it run correctly?

And in place of clicking on the query, you can certainly do

```
CurrentDB.execute "name of saved query goes here"
```

However, keep in mind that a PT query is raw T-SQL. What executes runs 100% on the server. This means that such query(s) cannot contain references to any form, or anything else. So you have to “pre-process” or create the value you wish to pass and modify the PT query. So your code of creating the SQL you have looks correct, but you then have to take that sql string and "set" the PT query.

The most easy way to do this is with code like this:

```
With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MyPass")
   .SQL = "sp_Submit '" & Me.cboNumber & "'"
   .Execute
End With
```

Of course if the PT query returns records, then you would go:

```
Dim rstRecords       As DAO.Recordset
With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MyPass")
   .SQL = "sp_Submit '" & Me.cboNumber & "'"
   .ReturnsRecords = True
   Set rstRecords = .OpenRecordset
End With
```

And to be fair, you likely should set “returns” records = false in the first example. You can do this in the property sheet of the save query, or in code like this:

```
With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MyPass")
   .SQL = "sp_Submit '" & Me.cboNumber & "'"
   .ReturnsRecords = False
   .Execute
End With
```

Note that you can use the one PT query over and over in your code. So once you ceated that one PT query, then you can use it to pass any new sql you wish, such as:

```
Dim rstRecords       As DAO.Recordset
With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MyPass")
   .SQL = "select * from tblHotels"
   .ReturnsRecords = True
  Set rstRecords = .OpenRecordset
End With
```

So you can "stuff" in any sql you want for that one PT query - and use it throughout your application.

Comment: Thank you! That helps very much. I appreciate your taking the time to explain it to me.  ~I upvoted and marked your answer as complete.